# Labels not adjusting distance automatically

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view which looks like so...

[image]

Now I want the label with the character `#` to maintain a same distance between any text in the label with the text "N/A"

i.e it should be shown as..

[image]

But now it is shown like so...

[image]

The constraints for the label with "N/A" is shown as...

[image]

And the constraints for the label with `#` is this...

[image]

What are the correct constraints that I should give so that there will be a proper distance always between "#" and "N/A"..?

Comment: Should the `#`be moving when the content of the label changes? if not check my answer.

Comment: yes..whatever the length of text in the label "N/A" be, `#` should move with it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove width constraint from "N/A" label and you're good to go.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 1. Change width to the label with "N/A" <= instead to = . and set it's trailing to # label with constant 2 or maybe more

Answer (score 0):

Just double click on label with "N/A" `width` constraint and set:

`Relation` value `Greater Than or Equal`

`Constant` value is `11`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pound sign to stay positioned in the same place and not follow the label around, you could set the alignment of the label to the right

```
label.textAlignment = .right
```

This way your design would stay consistent, and the content of the label could change without affecting the `#` position.